# Google-App-Scripts-Search files does not find spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, search, google-drive-api, getfiles

I created 3 untitled Google Spreadsheets to test this script. Search in My Drive for title:untitled or just untitled found all three, but in this script searchFiles method finds the Doc and the Slide but not the Spreadsheet and getFilesByName does not find any! I also tried "*untitled*" with the getFilesByName and still found none. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
function findUntitledFiles() {
  Logger.log("Begin findUntitledFiles()");
  var fileName = "*untitled*";
  var file, folder , filesIt , foldersIt;
  filesIt = DriveApp.searchFiles(' title contains "untitled" ') ;  // did not find spreadsheet
//  filesIt = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName) ;   // found none
  while (filesIt.hasNext() )  {
    file = filesIt.next() ;
    Logger.log("file.getName() = " + file.getName() );
    foldersIt = file.getParents() ;
    folderName = (foldersIt.hasNext()) ? foldersIt.next().getName() : "unknown" ;
    Logger.log( "folder  " + folderName + "    file name: " + file.getName() );
  } 
}
```

Comment: As a busy teacher, I tend to leave untitled files everywhere. When students do not complete assignments in classroom untitled files are created for each student. I like to clear up everything once in a while. I do not want an exact match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new spreadsheet for which I was the owner and now it is found by the script.

Answer (score 1):

**For DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName):**

fileName should contain the actual string of the filename.  As far as I know, no wildcard characters are permitted.  Also, a slide, doc, and sheet would all have different filenames - Untitled presentation, Untitled document, Untitled spreadsheet.  You could search for them this way (if you are only specifically looking at docs, sheets, slides):

```
function findUntitledFilesByName() {
    var fileCnt = 0;  
    var fileNames = ["Untitled presentation", "Untitled spreadsheet", "Untitled document"];

    for (var fileName in fileNames) {
        var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileNames[fileName]);
        while (files.hasNext()){
            var file = files.next();
            var folders = file.getParents();
            var folderName = (folders.hasNext()) ? folders.next().getName() : "unknown" ;
            console.log( "folder  " + folderName + "    file name: " + file.getName());
            fileCnt++;
        };
    }  
}
```

**For DriveApp.searchFiles(' title contains "untitled" '):**

Are you sure your code is not finding the spreadsheet?  When I tried your code, it found all the untitled files fine.  The only difference is that I have the variable declaration within the while statement so that there are no 'old' values within the variables.   Side note... since it uses a parameter of 'title contains', to search for anything that contains the word untitled, it will return results of ***any*** filename that has the word 'untitled' in it.  So if you have a file "One-Offs Untitled", that will be returned as a search result.  Please keep that in mind!

```
function findUntitledFilesUsingSearchFiles() {
    var fileCnt = 0;
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(' title contains "untitled" ') ;

    while (files.hasNext()){
        var file = files.next();
        var folders = file.getParents();
        var folderName = (folders.hasNext()) ? folders.next().getName() : "unknown" ;
        console.log( "folder  " + folderName + "    file name: " + file.getName());
        fileCnt++;      
    };
}
```

Comment: not an answer - works less well than original code.